# Determine data type of items in an STL container in a template method

Tags: c++, templates, stl, metaprogramming

I'm trying to write a template method to handle items in an STL container.  Getting details of the container is easy (and I use a std::enable_if clause to allow this template method to be called only if the container can be iterated over (detects a begin() method.))  I further need to know the data type held by the container.  Here's what works:

```
template <typename CONTAINER>
std::string doStuff(const CONTAINER & container) {
   using CONTAINER_TYPE = typename CONTAINER::value_type;
}
```

I can use `if constexpr` within this method to do certain things if I can also determine the type of the things held in the container.  Here's code that won't work but is like what I'm trying for:

```
template <typename CONTAINER, typename ITEM>
std::string doStuff(const CONTAINER<ITEM> & container) {
   using CONTAINER_TYPE = typename CONTAINER::value_type;
   using ITEM_TYPE = typename ITEM::value_type;
}
```

It completely makes sense why I can't invoke the method this way, but what could I do (either in invoking the method or with metaprogramming inside the method) to determine the type of the items in the container.  I'd like to do it such that it is known at compile time.

(I've tried a couple permutations of decltype and invoke_result and tons of searching but nothing is quite working yet.)  I've tried for example:

```
using ITEM_TYPE = std::invoke_result<&CONTAINER::begin>::type;
```

Of course, that returns an iterator type which needs to be dereferenced but '*' doesn't seem to work as expected here.

Comment: What is wrong with first method?

Comment: It isn't clear at all what you want to do with the second template. How do you call it? What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: The first one works fine.  I'm trying to add to it.

Comment: As you have already checked for `begin` how about `using CONTAINER_TYPE = decltype(*CONTAINER.begin());`

Comment: I assume you have SFINAE to not match the second template unless `ITEM::value_type` exists, like it doesn't do in a `std::vector<int>` for example?

Comment: The type of things held in the container is `CONTAINER::value_type`. Note: the type returned by `begin` might be a proxy object so I'm not sure you can get anything reliable out of that.

Comment: @C_Rod What are you trying to add to it?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Oh... I may be working on a bad assumption there then.  Maybe I need CONTAINER_TYPE = decltype(container) and ITEM_TYPE = CONTAINER::value_type.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @C_Rod yes, that would make more sense. Though, `CONTAINER_TYPE` would be redundant since you already have the `CONTAINER` template argument for the same type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use template template parameters:

```cpp
template <template <class, class...> class CONTAINER, class ITEM, class... REST>
std::string doStuff(const CONTAINER<ITEM, REST...>& container) {
   using CONTAINER_TYPE = ITEM; // or `typename CONTAINER<ITEM, REST...>::value_type`
   // This requires SFINAE to not match `ITEM`s without `value_type`:
   using ITEM_TYPE = typename ITEM::value_type;

   //...
}
```

Comment: This works.  Thank you.  My final uses typename instead of class but it works well.  Thank you.

Comment: @C_Rod Great! You're welcome!

Comment: Why not simply `using ITEM_TYPE = typename CONTAINER::value_type::value_type`? And how is this supposed to work with `std::vector<MyClass>` vs. `std::vector<std::vector<MyClass>>`?

Comment: `using CONTAINER_TYPE = ITEM;` seems really weird.  `ITEM` is the type of the element in the container, not the container type.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think `ITEM::value_type` is simpler than `CONTAINER::value_type::value_type` but both would work. If `MyClass` has a `value_type` typedef, it'll work. This function must not match types that doesn't have it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, the naming could be better but I followed OP:s pattern.

Comment: That template-template parameter discards `std::array` containers.

Comment: @Jarod42 True. One would need an overload for a `size_t` parameter for that, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7Mrf51s6T) but it'll still miss special classes with mixed types/non-type parameters I guess. Your solution definitely matches more.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow  I think I get what you meant now. You meant exactly what Jarod42 did, right?

Answer (score 3):

You might simply add extra `typename`

```
template <typename CONTAINER>
std::string doStuff(const CONTAINER& container){
   using CONTAINER_TYPE = typename CONTAINER::value_type;
   using ITEM_TYPE = typename CONTAINER_TYPE::value_type;
}
```

Possibly with some SFINAE (I will use C++20 way)

```
template <typename CONTAINER>
std::string doStuff(const CONTAINER& container)
requires(
    requires {
        typename CONTAINER::value_type::value_type;
    })
{
   using CONTAINER_TYPE = typename CONTAINER::value_type;
   using ITEM_TYPE = typename CONTAINER_TYPE::value_type;
}
```

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow pointed out that I wasn't quite getting the data types properly.  But that aside, this looks really nice.  I like the potential I see in the requires block there.  Is that C++20 onward?  I use C++17, I wonder if I could experiment with that some more with C++17.    Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: @C_Rod Yes, concepts requires at least C++20, but you could do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/jPn1PxPvG) to get a similar check in C++17.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  First of all, thanks for throwing together that example.  It's very helpful.  Second of all, that site (godbolt.org) with the C++ to assembly view looks super cool!  Wow.  That looks like a really nice place to test out things.